# React, TypeScript: Typing events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The question is about properly typing events in typescript

Have a function:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

someHandler = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  // event may be mouseclick or keypress
  // and to check if it is a keypress event i try to use instanceof.
  //
  // The logical way is to compare it with React.KeyboardEvent,

  if (event instanceof React.KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      // now i can access to event.key cause i know that event is keyboard event
    }
  }
  // but it throws error
  //
  // TS2339: Property 'KeyboardEvent' does not exist on typeof 'React'

  // ------

  // and as i expect i should compare it to KeyboardEvent
  //
  // that works
  if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      // now i can access to event.key
    }
  }
};
```

But the question is why it doesn't work so obviously?
Am i do something wrong?

Thank You!

Comment: how you are importing `react`?

Comment: @Harish `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: If you view the react source, you will see that `React` is actually a `namespace`. Perhaps this is not instanciable? - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: @Damien okay, but `event typeof React. KeyboardEvent` not works too, when although at the same time it works in function argument type definitions.

Comment: ```React.KeyboardEvent``` refers to the definition in React, which is an interface and can only be used in compile time, ```KeyboardEvent``` refers to ```window.KeyboardEvent``` and available in runtime.

Comment: @AsukaSong but what is a best way to type events in same situations?

Answer (score 0):

`React.KeyboardEvent` is the type definition and you cannot use it in runtime.
`event instanceof KeyboardEvent` will not work in react, since it sugarcoats the event with the `SyntheticBaseEvent` class. To test for event instances you should use:

```
if (
  e.nativeEvent instanceof KeyboardEvent
  && e.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter'
) {
  // now i can access to event.key
}
```